# Me falla el codigo CRUD

Tags: java, jdbc

Cuando ejecuto el código para que me haga delete, update, o addUser, me da error de null en algún String, como usuario o password.

Les muestro mi MySQL.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `curso`.`usuarios`;
```

id, usuario,nombre,apellidos,email,password,tipo, curso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Este es mi UserController

```
package com.User;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.User.dao.*;
import com.User.dao.UserDAOImplementation;

import sun.misc.Perf.GetPerfAction;

import com.User.User;

@WebServlet("/UserController")
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {

    private UserDAO dao;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String lIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";
    public static final String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/user.jsp";

    public UserController() {
        dao = new UserDAOImplementation();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward = "";
        String action = request.getParameter( "action" );

        if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "delete" ) ) {
            forward = lIST_USER;
            String usuario= (request.getParameter("usuairo")) ;
            dao.deleteUser(usuario);
            request.setAttribute("user", dao.getAllUser() );
        }
        else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "edit" ) ) {
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            String usuario = ( request.getParameter("usuario") );
            User user = dao.getUserById(usuario);
            request.setAttribute("User", user);
        }
        else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "insert" ) ) {
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        }
        else {
            forward = lIST_USER;
            request.setAttribute("user", dao.getAllUser() );
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher( forward );
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsuario( request.getParameter( "usuario" ) );
        user.setNombre( request.getParameter( "nombre" ) );
        user.setApellidos( request.getParameter( "apellidos" ) );
        user.setEmail( request.getParameter( "email" ) ) ;
        user.setPassword( request.getParameter( "password" ) ) ;
        user.setTipo( request.getParameter( "tipo" ) ) ;
        user.setCurso( request.getParameter( "curso" ) ) ;      
        String id = request.getParameter("id");

        if( id == null || id.isEmpty() ) 
            dao.addUser(user);
        else {


            dao.updateUser(user);
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher( lIST_USER );
        request.setAttribute("user", dao.getAllUser());
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

#### User

```
package com.User;

import java.util.List;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String usuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String tipo;
    private String curso;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario= usuario;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void  setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }
   public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public String getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }
    public void setCurso(String curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", usuario=" + usuario + ", nombre=" + nombre
                + ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ",  email="
                + email + ", password=" + password +", tipo="
                + tipo + ",  curso="
                + curso + "]";
    }


    public static List<User> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Y por último mi Dao

```java
package com.User.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.User.*;
    import com.User.util.DbUtil;



    public class UserDAOImplementation implements UserDAO {

        private Connection conn;

        public UserDAOImplementation() {
            conn = DbUtil.getConnection();
        }
        @Override
        public void addUser( User user ) {
            try {
                String query = "insert into usuarios (usuario, nombre, apellidos, email , password , tipo , curso) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( query );
        preparedStatement.setString( 1, user.getUsuario() );
        preparedStatement.setString( 2, user.getNombre() );
        preparedStatement.setString( 3, user.getApellidos() );
        preparedStatement.setString( 4, user.getEmail() );
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getTipo());
        preparedStatement.setString(7, user.getCurso());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void deleteUser( String usuario) {
    try {
        String query = "delete from usuarios where Id=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void updateUser( User user ) {
    try {
        String query = "update usuarios set usuario=?, nombre=?, apellidos=?, email=? , password=?, tipo=?, curso=?,where id=?";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( query );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 1, user.getUsuario() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 2, user.getNombre() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 3, user.getApellidos() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 4, user.getEmail() );
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPassword());
                    preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getTipo());
                    preparedStatement.setString(7, user.getCurso());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(8, user.getId());
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from usuarios");
while (rs.next()) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
user.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
user.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
user.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
user.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
user.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
            users.add(user);


        }   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

    }
    return users;
}


public User getUserById(String usuario) {
    User user = new User();
    try {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.
                prepareStatement("select * from usuarios where usuario=?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
      user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
  user.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
  user.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
  user.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
  user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
  user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
  user.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
  user.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user;
}
@Override
public List<User> getAllUser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Me da fallos de null usuario.

¿Por qué me puede fallar el códido? Ahora mismo el update y el addUser me hacen lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando JDBC? ¿Te llegan datos desde las peticiones (puedes comprobarlo con un System.out o algún Logger)? ¿Te lanza una excepción tu código o solo inserta y/o actualiza nulos en la tabla usuarios?

Answer (score 0):

He estado leyendo tú código, sobre la actualización que te falla es al preparar tu consulta, antes del WHERE tienes una coma extra. Como consejo, ya que has montado una clase de 'conexión', te aconsejo utilizar alguna de preparación automática de consultas, como está que tengo desarrollada: [ENLACE](https://github.com/ticdenis/API_DNA/tree/master/JAVA/bases_de_datos)

Revisa si lo que recibes en las peticiones llega correctamente, y los nombres de los campos en las tablas de MySQL.

He adaptado tú código y corregido lo comentado, ahora es mucho más legible y menos propenso a errores de escritura y no técnicos.

```
public class UserDAOImplementation implements UserDAO {

    public UserDAOImplementation(url, port, database, user, password) {
        if (MySQL.tryConnection(url, port, database, user, password).ping()) {
            System.out.println("Conexión MySQL-JDBC establecida");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, nombre, apellidos, email , password , tipo , curso) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        String[] params = new String[]{
            user.getUsuario(), user.getNombre(), user.getApellidos(), 
            user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(), user.getTipo(), user.getCurso()
        };
        MySQL.insert(query, params, (rowsInserted) -> {
            System.out.println( rowsInserted != 0 ? "addUser - SUCCESS" : "addUser - ERROR" );
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String usuario) {
        String query = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE Id = ?;";
        String[] params = new String[]{ usuario };
        MySQL.delete(query, params, (rowsDeleted) -> {
            System.out.println( rowsDeleted != 0 ? "deleteUser - SUCCESS" : "deleteUser - ERROR" );
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        String query = "UPDATE usuarios SET usuario = ?, nombre = ?, apellidos = ?, email = ?, password = ?, tipo = ?, curso = ? WHERE id = ?;";
        String[] params = new String[]{
            user.getUsuario(), user.getNombre(), user.getApellidos(), 
            user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(), user.getTipo(), 
            user.getCurso(), user.getId()
        };
        MySQL.update(query, params, (rowsUpdated) -> {
            System.out.println( rowsUpdated != 0 ? "updateUser - SUCCESS" : "updateUser - ERROR" );
        });
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios;";
        String[] params = new String[]{};
        MySQL.select(query, params, (resultSet) -> {
            users = new ArrayList<User>();
            while (resultSet.next()) { 
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                user.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                user.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                user.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                user.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
                user.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
                users.add(user);
            }
            System.out.println( resultSet != null && !users.isEmpty() ? "getAllUsers - SUCCESS" : "getAllUsers - ERROR" );
        });
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(String usuario) {
        User user;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?;";
        String[] params = new String[]{ usuario };

        MySQL.select(query, params, (resultSet) -> {
            while (resultSet.next()) { 
                user = new User();
                user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                user.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                user.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                user.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                user.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
                user.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
            }
            System.out.println( resultSet != null && user != null ? "getUserById - SUCCESS" : "getUserById - ERROR" );
        });
        return user;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que no tengas un valor null o vacio debes validar antes de realizar la ejecución, aquí le hice algunas correcciones a tu DAO:

```
package com.User.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.User.*;
import com.User.util.DbUtil;



    public class UserDAOImplementation implements UserDAO {

        private Connection conn;

        public UserDAOImplementation() {
            conn = DbUtil.getConnection();
        }
        @Override
        public void addUser( User user ) {
            if(user != null && user.getUsuario().trim.equals("")){//Así con cada uno de los demás campos de tu objeto user
                try {
                    String query = "insert into usuarios (usuario, nombre, apellidos, email , password , tipo , curso) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( query );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 1, user.getUsuario() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 2, user.getNombre() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 3, user.getApellidos() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 4, user.getEmail() );
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPassword());
                    preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getTipo());
                    preparedStatement.setString(7, user.getCurso());
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void deleteUser( String usuario) {
            if(usuario != null && usuario.trim().equals("")){
                try {
                    String query = "delete from usuarios where Id=?";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void updateUser( User user ) {
            if(user != null && user.getUsuario().trim.equals("")){//Así con cada uno de los demás de tu objeto user
                try {
                    String query = "update usuarios set usuario=?, nombre=?, apellidos=?, email=? , password=?, tipo=?, curso=? where id=?";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( query );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 1, user.getUsuario() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 2, user.getNombre() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 3, user.getApellidos() );
                    preparedStatement.setString( 4, user.getEmail() );
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPassword());
                    preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getTipo());
                    preparedStatement.setString(7, user.getCurso());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(8, user.getId());
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public List<User> getAllUsers() {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
            try {
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from usuarios");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                    user.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                    user.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                    user.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
                    user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                    user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                    user.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
                    user.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
                    users.add(user);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

            }
            return users;
        }


        public User getUserById(String usuario) {
            User user = new User();
            if(usuario != null && usuario.trim().equals("")){
                try {
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.
                    prepareStatement("select * from usuarios where usuario=?");
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, usuario);
                    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) {
                          user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                      user.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                      user.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                      user.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
                      user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                      user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                      user.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
                      user.setCurso(rs.getString("curso"));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return user;
        }
        @Override
        public List<User> getAllUser() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

}
```

Y en tu UserController:

```
        String action = request.getParameter( "action" );
        if(action != null && !action.trim.equals(""){
            if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "delete" ) ) {
                forward = lIST_USER;
                //String usuario= (request.getParameter("usuairo")) ;Mal
                String usuario= (request.getParameter("usuario")) ;
                if(usuario != null && !usuario.trim.equals(""){
                    dao.deleteUser(usuario);
                    request.setAttribute("user", dao.getAllUser() );
                }
            }
            else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "edit" ) ) {
                forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
                String usuario = ( request.getParameter("usuario") );
                if(usuario != null && !usuario.trim.equals(""){
                    User user = dao.getUserById(usuario);
                    request.setAttribute("User", user);
                }
            }
            else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "insert" ) ) {
                forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            }
            else {
                forward = lIST_USER;
                request.setAttribute("user", dao.getAllUser() );
            }
        }else{
            //Aquí hacer algo en caso de venir null o vacio
        }
```